# Tomcat 6 show weird message in catalina log

Tags: logging, tomcat6, catalina

I see tons of this error message in my Tomcat Catalina log:

```
Invalid chunk starting at byte [0] and ending at byte [0] with a value of [null] ignored
```

Does anyone has an idea what it means?

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor bug that was introduced in Apache 6.0.35 and fixed in Apache 6.0.36. It is caused by parameters with more than one '&' character:

From [the changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html):

> Tomcat 6.0.36 (jfclere)   released 2012-10-19
>
> > Catalina
> >
> > > [...]
> > >
> > > [image] Do not flag extra '&' characters in parameters as parse errors. (kkolinko)